# empty folder takes inodes

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-14.04, ext4

I'm running a ubuntu 14.04.1
While I have diskspace remaining, I do have a 100% inode usage:

```
ubuntu@ipsec-2:~$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     524288 520606   3682  100% /
```

the device is `/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)`

when using stat, I found that a lot of inodes went into /media:

```
ubuntu@ipsec-2:/$ stat -t -c "%n: %i" ./* | sort -k2 -n
{omit <100k inodes for clarity}
./initrd.img: 124172
./bin: 262145
./home: 262147
./lib64: 262148
./boot: 393217
./etc: 393218
./lib: 393219
./media: 393220
```

When going into /media, it is empty:

```
ubuntu@ipsec-2:/$ cd /media
ubuntu@ipsec-2:/media$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 16  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Mar 28 09:25 ..
```

I've already tried rebooting the server to see if this would release the inodes, but to no avail.
Using lsof | grep media did not work either to see if some process had them in use, even if they were deleted.

is there a way to remove inodes, or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you the filesystem inode limit is reached, you need to show how your inodes are used. The command you used will show the inode number of each file or directory. This is **not** the same as number of inodes used.

```
$ stat -t -c "%n: %i" ./*
```

If you want to see the largest directory in inode usage, you can use a command like this (the last directory shown in the output):

```
$ find / -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n
```

Comment: "the inode number of each file or directory" means the amount of inodes permitted for that directory?

Comment: @ShadowFlame: It is just a numeric value to represent an identifier of the inode.

Comment: thanks, didn't know this. I misread the manpage